# Can't compare strings in Python

Tags: python, string, compare, match, readline

I have this code that should open and read two text files, and match when a word is present in both. The match is represented by printing "SUCESS" and by writing the word to a temp.txt file.

```
dir = open('listac.txt','r')
path = open('paths.txt','r')
paths = path.readlines()
paths_size = len(paths)
matches = open('temp.txt','w')
dirs = dir.readlines()

for pline in range(0,len(paths)):
        for dline in range(0,len(dirs)):
                p = paths[pline].rstrip('\n').split(".")[0].replace(" ", "")
                dd = dirs[dline].rstrip('\n').replace(" ", "")
                #print p.lower()
                #print dd.lower()
                if (p.lower() == dd.lower()):
                        print "SUCCESS\n"
                        matches.write(str(p).lower() + '\n')
```

listac.txt is formatted as

```
/teetetet
/eteasdsa
/asdasdfsa
/asdsafads
.
. 
...etc
```

paths.txt is formated as

```
/asdadasd.php/asdadas/asdad/asd
/adadad.html/asdadals/asdsa/asd
.
.
...etc
```

hence I use the split function in order to get the first /asadasda (within paths.txt) before the dot. 
The problem is that the words never seem to match, I have even printed out each comparison before each IF statement and they are equal, is there something else that Python does before comparing strings?

=======

Thanks everyone for the help. As suggested by you, I cleaned the code so It ended up like this:

```
dir = open('listac.txt','r')
path = open('paths.txt','r')
#paths = path.readlines()
#paths_size = len(paths)

for line in path:
        p = line.rstrip().split(".")[0].replace(" ", "")
        for lines in dir:
                d = str(lines.rstrip())
                if p == d:
                        print p + " = " + d
```

Apparently, having p declared and initialized before entering the second for loop makes a difference in the comparison down the road. When I declared p and d within the second for loop, it wouldn't work. I don't know the reason for that but If someone does, I am listening :)

Thanks again!

Comment: In your examples, there is no match.

Comment: Too complicated. Don't use `for pline in range(0,len(paths))`, just iterate over the elements with `for pline in paths`. And why `rstrip('\n')`. There might be an extra `\r`. Just use `rstrip()`.

Comment: You can also move `p = ...` outside the inner for loop since it's doing the same calculation each time.

Comment: Rather than compare every possible pair from two lists, find the intersection of two sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd have to see more of your data set to see why you aren't getting matches. I've refactored some of your code to be more *pythonic*.

```
dirFile = open('listac.txt','r')
pathFile = open('paths.txt','r')
paths = pathFile.readlines()
dirs = dirFile.readlines()

matches = open('temp.txt','w')

for pline in paths:
    p = pline.rstrip('\n').split(".")[0].replace(" ", "")
    for dline in dirs:
        dd = dline.rstrip('\n').replace(" ", "")
        #print p.lower()
        #print dd.lower()
        if p.lower() == dd.lower():
            print "SUCCESS\n"
            matches.write(str(p).lower() + '\n')
```

Comment: +1, but you can avoid the horrible nested loop by converting `dirs` into a set first (`dirs = {line.lower() for line in dirFile}` and then just check `if p.lower() in dirs`), and just iterate over the file directly, avoiding the `readlines()` and all those `rstrip()`s entirely.

Comment: @TimPietzcker for sure. I would write this completely differently. I think it's more helpful to ease beginners into such things.

Answer (score 7):

While we're reading the entire datafiles into memory anyway, why not try to use `sets` and get the intersection?:

```
def format_data(x):
    return x.rstrip().replace(' ','').split('.')[0].lower()

with open('listac.txt') as dirFile:
     dirStuff = set( format_data(dline) for dline in dirFile )

with open('paths.txt') as pathFile:
     intersection = dirStuff.intersection( format_data(pline) for pline in pathFile )

for elem in intersection:
    print "SUCCESS\n"
    matches.write(str(elem)+"\n")
```

I've used the same `format_data` function for both datasets, since they look more or less the same, but you can use more than one function if you please.  Also note that this solution only reads 1 of the two files into memory.  The intersection with the other should be calculated lazily.

As pointed out in the comments, this does not make any attempt to preserve the order.  However, if you really need to preserve the order, try this:

```
<snip>
...
</snip>

with open('paths.txt') as pathFile:
    for line in pathFile:
        if format_line(line) in dirStuff:
           print "SUCCESS\n"
           #...
```

Comment: This will lead to a different output, though, since the order of the lines will be lost. Most probably this won't matter.

Comment: I prefer `a & b` before `a.intersection(b)`.  "What is in a & b" == "What is in a & in b".

Comment: Too bad that operators like ∩ are not ASCII and thus not (yet) part of Python ;-)

Comment: @Alfe -- The problem with `a & b` in this case (verses `a.intersection`) is that the operator form *Must* have sets whereas the method form doesn't need the second argument to be a set.  In other words, we can create the intersection without reading both files into memory if we use the method form.

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- I don't think order should matter, but I've added a statement saying that we aren't preserving order.  I've also added a way to keep the order if the OP desires.

Comment: Again I think that accepting an answer within the first 10 minutes isn't a good idea and should be prohibited.  I cringe on seeing that now the nested loop stuff is optically preferred above the set solution.  And I also don't think that user1663160 fares good with it.

Comment: Thank you all, the order did not matter in this case. I just needed to have the matches returned

Comment: Using the `.index()` stuff is no good idea to reestablish the order anyway.  Better just walk linearly through the input which provides the order and use `in` on a set of the other input to determine whether a match is found.

Comment: @Alfe -- Thanks.  Updated.  I don't know why I was making it more complicated (and slow) than it needed to be ...

Comment: Okay, now consider also removing the last sentence (about being less efficient) because I don't thinks that is true anymore ;-)

Comment: @Alfe -- Wow, you're really interested in this question ;^).  Thanks.  (whenever I leave stuff like that, you can feel free to edit it yourself -- I don't mind.)